# What are the non-practical features of a sterling engine that cause the internal combustion engine to be used instead?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, automotive-engineering, combustion, engines

What are the non-practical features of a sterling engine that cause the internal combustion engine to be used instead (in a car)? (e.g. price, size, the power to weight ratio, etc.)

Can you name any that aren't as obvious as those stated above?
Please provide answers that aren't obvious but are still relevant.

Comment: https://youtu.be/saCdvAp5cow     This video is about a swedish submarine using sterling engine.I think this might interest you.

Comment: @Mohan will look at it soon thanks

Comment: what's your research so far? So we don't repeat stuff that you allready know.

Comment: I believe it's because they're bigger, heavier, and "want" to run at a constant speed -- but I learned all of that from the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this for one of the other features but would still like more. 
City driving where there is stop-start activity is not beneficial for the usage of sterling engines as well as the fact that you are not able to link the cylinders of multiple sterling engines to one another like you can with a combustion engine.

Comment: Ethan, either of those limitations are not difficult to overcome  with proper transmission/drivetrain design. I think you will find that supply chain and infrastructure for design/manufacturing of Sterling engines at scale is one of the primary challenges which prevents greater adoption.